# File collection into a specific g-drive folder onFormSubmit in Google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I'm trying to create a Google form which collects documents, and stores it into a specific folder (with a specific name that is submitted in the form). The code mostly works correctly when users upload a single file in the question where they need to upload a file, but runs into problems when someone uploads multiple files into a question. I think since the response is stored in a comma separated format for more than one file, my code is not reading it as an ID.

Here is my code

```
function saveDetailsInFolder(e) {

  var submissionResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();

  var name = submissionResponses[0].getResponse(); //get name submitted in the form

  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("My desired parent folder"); //get the parent folder, put the ID in the quotes

  var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(name); //create a new folder with the name submitted in the form

var fileUploads = submissionResponses.filter(item => item.getItem().getType().toString() === 'FILE_UPLOAD');

  for (var x=0; x<fileUploads.length;x++){

    var fileUploadID = fileUploads[x].getResponse();

  DriveApp.getFileById(fileUploadID).makeCopy(newFolder)

  }

}
```

From some testing, I came to the conclusion that for questions where users upload multiple files, form stores it in a comma separated format, and when it is passed in the variable for "getFileById", it's unable to get it.

I need a way to get all documents. One way I can personally think of, is combining all response IDs, single file.upload questions and multiple file upload questions in an array and go through it one by one and upload them to the folder, but I can't seem to do it due to insufficient knowledge about arrays.

Please know if there's a solution for this, or a different method that I can use to get the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function saveDetailsInFolder(e) {
  var submissionResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var name = submissionResponses[0].getResponse();
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("My desired parent folder"); // Please set your folder ID.
  var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(name);
  var fileUploads = submissionResponses.filter(item => item.getItem().getType().toString() === 'FILE_UPLOAD');
  for (var x = 0; x < fileUploads.length; x++) {
    var fileUploadID = fileUploads[x].getResponse();
    if (!Array.isArray(fileUploadID)) {
      fileUploadID = [fileUploadID];
    }
    fileUploadID.forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).makeCopy(newFolder));
  }
}
```

- In the current stage, when a single file is uploaded, a string value of the file ID is returned. In your script, it's `fileUploadID`. On the other hand, when multiple files are uploaded, an array including the file IDs is returned.
- In this modification, when the value of `fileUploadID` is not an array, the value of `fileUploadID` is put into an array. And, the file IDs of an array of `fileUploadID` are processed in the loop.

#### Reference:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: This works. Could you provide a little more context on how the last line works? Where does the "Id" come from and how does it know to get the details from the array? We have not declared it as such...

Comment: @Joshua Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Where does the "Id" come from and how does it know to get the details from the array?`, in the case of the OnSubmit trigger on Google Form, when a single file is uploaded, a string value of the file ID is returned. When multiple files are uploaded, an array including the file IDs is returned. In your script, this value can be retrieved by `var fileUploadID = fileUploads[x].getResponse();`. `fileUploadID` is a string value or an array. This is from the event object. If my explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Joshua In my modification, when `fileUploadID` is a string value, it is put into an array. And, the file ID is processed in an array. In this case, when `fileUploadID` is an array, it can be directly used. If my explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: so how does "Id" operate without being declared? It is a variable right? In this line of code: fileUploadID.forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id)

Comment: @Joshua Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `so how does "Id" operate without being declared?`. If you are saying about `id` of `fileUploadID.forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id)`, this document might be useful. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)